# Java get mouse position on click on Gui

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, mouseevent

I would like to get the mouse position on click on the swing window itself, NOT on the console on eclipse. Can anyone know how to do that? I'm sorry if it's an obvious question, i'm a beginner. Thx in advance.

Here is the code i got. I somehow found a piece here, but it doesn't really help me like i want.

```
package shapes;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class mouse {

public static void main(String[] args){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    frame.add(panel);
    panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {


        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int x=e.getX();
            int y=e.getY();
            System.out.println(x+","+y);
        }

 }); frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setSize(200, 200); frame.setVisible(true);




}

}
```

Comment: When you say "get the mouse position on click on the swing window itself" do you mean that you want to *display* it on the Swing window or do you just mean you want the coordinates of the pointer when the pointer is on the Swing window (btw I do think you mean *pointer* and not *mouse*).

Comment: yes i'm sorry , i meant the position of the pointer. I want the coordinate of the pointer relative to the swing window whenever i click it, i want it display right where i click. Can you help out?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sure, just give me a moment and I will submit an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print the location to a `JLabel`:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel();
panel.add(label);
panel.setLayout(null);
frame.add(panel);
panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        label.setText("X: "+x+" \t Y: "+y); // this sets the JLabel's text
        label.setBounds(x, y, label.getText().length()*2, 20);
    }
});
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setSize(200, 200);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

results in this:

[image: this is the result]

Comment: @IanTwy then please upvote and accept the answer. that way, when others find this question, they know this answer works

Comment: i want to upvote, but it says it doesn't publicly display here due to less than 15 reputation.

Comment: @IanTwy then you can accept the answer. there's a tick symbol under the question score, if you press it, then you accept the answer.

Comment: thx a lot, but do you know how to display the coordinate next to where i click? and i want the other coordinate to stay on the screen as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [PointerInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/PointerInfo.html) class, it can help you.

Comment: he wants it to display on the JFrame

Comment: On Stack Overflow the policy is that a link is insufficient for an answer. If a link is your answer then it should just be a comment.